# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder error while running jhipster micro services

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, slf4j, jhipster-gateway

Jhipster version:
7.9.3

Sharing the exception log below (same error also shows up in integration test)

It fails in bootRun task

```
18:10:34.171 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@729164cf
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:238)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:79)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:56)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:56)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:299)
        at com.kursaha.flash.FlashApp.main(FlashApp.java:70)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Do you have a dependency on the classpath that supplies this class? Like slf4-jsimple or logback?

Comment: Able to fix it, have to force downgrade the logback.             force group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.11'

Comment: @nishantpathak Searching for hours for this to fix my Spring Boot application! Thank you so much.